# Inconsistent indentation: 9 spaces used for identation

Tags: server, gitlab, haml

I tried to modify the Gitlab `index.html.haml` file in server. I just want to display my message instead of Default message. So I modified `14` line to following code

```
%i GitLab team
can add the members. Please request the team if you need.
```

But I get following error in `production.log`

[image]

I modified the space before the `%i GitLab team` to `8` space and tried the same thing. But I got the same issue. I tried `restart` and `reconfigure` also in the machine. But it is not worked. It is not worked even I modified the content to original old content. How can I overcome this?

Comment: Are you using tabs or spaces?

Comment: Also what do you mean by "I modified the space before the `%i GitLab team` to 8 space"?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks for your valuable help, I used tabs instead of space.  Now I overcame this issue. Thank you very much

Comment: Yeah, in most things ruby you use 2 spaces, not tabs. And you _definitely_ don't want to mix tabs and spaces. Set up your editor to expand tabs to 2 spaces (so called soft tabs or smart tabs)